# DataSnapshot cannot be cast to Adapter

Tags: java, android, firebase-realtime-database, firebaseui

I have a problem, I am creating an Adapter for RecyclerView and in order to create it I extend the class using FirebaseRecyclerAdapter, but I get an error and I don’t know how to solve it, maybe someone can tell me something. I found a similar example on the Internet that it is possible to extend a class in this way, but either I am doing something wrong, or it is no longer possible to extend the class in this way. Thanks a lot for any help

here is my adapter:

```
public class PostAdapterTest extends FirebaseRecyclerAdapter <Posts, PostAdapterTest.postsViewHolder> { //error the error is here
    private BottomSheetDialog bottomSheetDialog;
    private Context mContext;
    private Boolean downloadOrOpen = false;
    private boolean buttonStatus = true;
    private DatabaseReference likesRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("Likes");
    private FirebaseUser mFirebaseUser = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser();

    private String difficulty = null;

    private int likesCounter;
    private ReadWritePermissions mReadWritePermissions;

    public PostAdapterTest(@NonNull FirebaseRecyclerOptions<Posts> postsFirebaseRecyclerOptions,  ReadWritePermissions mReadWritePermissions, Context mContext)
    {
        super(postsFirebaseRecyclerOptions);
        this.mContext = mContext;
        this.mReadWritePermissions = mReadWritePermissions;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull PostAdapterTest.postsViewHolder holder, int position, @NonNull Posts model) {
        final String postKey = getRef(position).getKey();
        String postUid = model.getPostId();

        holder.nickname.setText(model.getNickname());
        holder.country.setText(model.getCountry());
        holder.title.setText(model.getCountry());
        holder.days.setText(model.getDays());
        holder.kilometers.setText(model.getKilometers());
        holder.description.setText(model.getDescription());

        difficulty = model.getDifficulty();

        holder.map.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Uri mapUri = Uri.parse(model.getMap());
                mapOptions(mapUri);
            }
        });

        holder.comments.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                CommentsFragment commentsFragment = new CommentsFragment();
                Bundle args = new Bundle();
                args.putString("postId", postUid);

                commentsFragment.setArguments(args);

                FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = ((FragmentActivity)mContext).getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
                fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.frame_container, commentsFragment);
                fragmentTransaction.addToBackStack(null);
                fragmentTransaction.commit();

            }
        });

        holder.setLikeButtonStatus(postKey);

        holder.likes.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                buttonStatus = true;

                likesRef.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot snapshot) {
                        if(buttonStatus == true)
                        {
                            if(snapshot.child(postKey).hasChild(mFirebaseUser.getUid()))
                            {
                                likesRef.child(postKey).child(mFirebaseUser.getUid()).removeValue();
                                buttonStatus = false;
                            }else
                            {
                                likesRef.child(postKey).child(mFirebaseUser.getUid()).setValue(true);
                                buttonStatus = false;
                            }
                        }
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError error) {

                    }
                });

                switch (difficulty)
                {
                    case "Easy":
                        holder.difficulty.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_easy);
                        break;

                    case "Difficult":
                        holder.difficulty.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_difficult);
                        break;

                    case "Hard":
                        holder.difficulty.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_hard);
                        break;
                }

                ArrayList<Slider> sliderArrayList = new ArrayList<>();

                Picasso.get().load(model.getAvatarUri()).into(holder.avatarUri);
            }
        });
    }

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public PostAdapterTest.postsViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext())
                .inflate(R.layout.posts, parent, false);
        return new PostAdapterTest.postsViewHolder(view);
    }

    class postsViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder
    {
        public CircleImageView avatarUri;
        public TextView nickname, country, title, days, likesNum, kilometers,description, fileSize, fileName;
        public SliderView mSliderView;
        public ImageView comments, save, difficulty;
        public ImageButton likes;
        public ImageButton more;
        public LinearLayout map;

        public postsViewHolder(@NonNull View itemView) {
            super(itemView);

            avatarUri = itemView.findViewById(R.id.posts_profile_picture);
            nickname = itemView.findViewById(R.id.posts_nickname);
            country = itemView.findViewById(R.id.posts_country);
            title = itemView.findViewById(R.id.posts_title);
            days = itemView.findViewById(R.id.posts_days);
            difficulty = itemView.findViewById(R.id.posts_difficulty);
            mSliderView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.posts_images);
            likes = itemView.findViewById(R.id.posts_likes);
            comments = itemView.findViewById(R.id.posts_comments);
            save = itemView.findViewById(R.id.posts_save);
            likesNum = itemView.findViewById(R.id.posts_likes_number);
            description = itemView.findViewById(R.id.posts_description);
            more = itemView.findViewById(R.id.posts_more);
            kilometers = itemView.findViewById(R.id.posts_distance);
            fileSize = itemView.findViewById(R.id.posts_uploaded_file_size);
            fileName = itemView.findViewById(R.id.posts_uploaded_file_name);
            map = itemView.findViewById(R.id.posts_map_layout);
        }

        public void setLikeButtonStatus(final String key)
        {
            mFirebaseUser = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser();

            likesRef.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
                @Override
                public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot snapshot) {
                    likesCounter = (int)snapshot.child(key).getChildrenCount();
                    if(snapshot.child(key).hasChild(mFirebaseUser.getUid()))
                    {
                        likes.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_liked_red);
                        likesNum.setText(likesCounter + " Likes");
                    }else if(likesCounter == 0)
                    {
                        likes.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_unliked_red);
                        likesNum.setText("");
                    }else
                    {
                        likes.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_unliked_red);
                        likesNum.setText(likesCounter + " Likes");
                    }
                }

                @Override
                public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError error) {

                }
            });
        }
    }

    private void mapOptions(Uri mapUri)
    {
       
    }
}
```

Logcat:

```
Process: com.company.android.myapplication, PID: 8349
    java.lang.ClassCastException: com.google.firebase.database.DataSnapshot cannot be cast to com.company.android.myapplication.Posts
        at com.company.android.myapplication.test.PostAdapterTest.onBindViewHolder(PostAdapterTest.java:44)
        at com.firebase.ui.database.FirebaseRecyclerAdapter.onBindViewHolder(FirebaseRecyclerAdapter.java:149)
        at androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView$Adapter.onBindViewHolder(RecyclerView.java:7254)
        at androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView$Adapter.bindViewHolder(RecyclerView.java:7337)
        at androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView$Recycler.tryBindViewHolderByDeadline(RecyclerView.java:6194)
        at androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView$Recycler.tryGetViewHolderForPositionByDeadline(RecyclerView.java:6460)
        at androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView$Recycler.getViewForPosition(RecyclerView.java:6300)
        at androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView$Recycler.getViewForPosition(RecyclerView.java:6296)
        at androidx.recyclerview.widget.LinearLayoutManager$LayoutState.next(LinearLayoutManager.java:2330)
        at androidx.recyclerview.widget.LinearLayoutManager.layoutChunk(LinearLayoutManager.java:1631)
        at androidx.recyclerview.widget.LinearLayoutManager.fill(LinearLayoutManager.java:1591)
        at androidx.recyclerview.widget.LinearLayoutManager.onLayoutChildren(LinearLayoutManager.java:668)
        at androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView.dispatchLayoutStep2(RecyclerView.java:4309)
        at androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView.dispatchLayout(RecyclerView.java:4012)
        at androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView.onLayout(RecyclerView.java:4578)
```

Comment: At which particular line of code are you getting that error?

Comment: @AlexMamo the first line of adapter class I wrote the comment there

Comment: Your title doesn't match your stack trace

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> java.lang.ClassCastException: com.google.firebase.database.DataSnapshot cannot be cast to com.company.android.myapplication.Posts

You just can't cast the `DataSnapshot` to your own pojo `Posts`, you have to get the `value` from the `DataSnapshot`. Also, make sure that the `DataSnapshot` schema & your pojo `Posts` schema matched properly to parse the `DataSnapshot` value to `Posts`.

Also, it's really bad approach to make queries from Adapter directly or calling activity or making Firebase transaction. You should pass callback to the Adapter and handle the logic on your fragment/activity.

Comment: can you show me an example please ?

Comment: Posts post = (Posts) postSnapshot.child("posts").getValue();

Comment: athe same problem is that I cannot do all the logic in a class or activity, since I have several activities in which I need to fill the RecyclerView and because of this I get duplicate code

Comment: Then you should find a better way to acheive your requirments.